# UIActivityIndicatorView not spinning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I have this problem where I am adding an `UIActivityIndicatorView` to a `UIScrollView`; Everything is working fine, except it does not start spinning unless the `UIScrollView` is scrolled.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you.

here is some code:

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loaderActivity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    loaderActivity.center = CGPointMake(87/2,y+56/2);
    loaderActivity.tag=tag;
    [mainScrollView addSubview:loaderActivity];
    [loaderActivity startAnimating];
    [loaderActivity release];
```

Comment: can you please add code here for more clearance about question.

Comment: one more thing to start activity running you need to call method after activity added in view or on any event like button click or just set performselector with minor delay.

Comment: are you performing another task in the main thread? if so, the main thread will be used for that task and will stop the animation until that task is finished.

Comment: @sch,Neel i've added some code. Let me know if you want something more specific

Comment: @Felipe All other tasks are in their respective threads. The Activity indicator will only start to spin when i scroll, even when the task is not finished

Comment: @NagiObeid what happens if you call `setNeedDisplay` in your scrollview just after the `UIActivityIndicatorView`'s `startAnimating`?

Comment: I have exactly same problem, did you ever work that out? My UIActivityIndicatorView ignores [startAnimating] and will only start animating after I scroll or press a button (even when I interact with a control outside the view hierarchy where the UIActivityIndicatorView lies)

Comment: ok, that works for me, although now my UIActivityIndicatorView does now appear in its superview until *after* the set delay: `[spinner performSelector:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];` The delay needs to be material unfortunately, > 0.5 in my case.

Answer (score 9):

You need to call `startAnimating` on the activity indicator to have it animate. Alternatively in interface builder you can tick the "animating" tickbox.

Comment: A better question is what use is a non-animating activity indicator and why would that be the default state?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that it's not animating until you scroll in the scroll view is a symptom that your call to startAnimating is happening in a background thread. UIKit calls should be made in the main thread.

You can verify that it's happening in a background thread by adding code like this:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    NSLog(@"Running on main thread.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Running on background thread.");
}
```

You'll want to make sure all of the code you showed in your question is running on the main thread. To do this, you can change your code to look something like this:

```
// this code would be wherever your existing code was
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addActivityIndicatorToView:) withObject:mainScrollView waitUntilDone:YES];

// this would be a new method in the same class that your existing code is in
- (void) addActivityIndicatorToView:(UIView*) view {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loaderActivity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    loaderActivity.center = CGPointMake(87/2,y+56/2);
    loaderActivity.tag=tag;
    [view addSubview:loaderActivity];
    [loaderActivity startAnimating];
    [loaderActivity release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(87/2,y+56/2);
[activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityIndicator.tag=tag;
[mainScrollView addSubview:loaderActivity];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[activityIndicator release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Had an issue where I made the `startAnimating` call in the `viewDidLoad` and didn't work. I moved the call in the `viewWillAppear` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the animator in a different thread.

```
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showProgress) object:nil];
[thread start];

//do whatever your want here

//call this when you want it stop animating
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [thread release];


- (void)showProgress{

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

}
```